# Images on my server inside a password protected directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have images inside a password protected directory, but I want to show some of these images on the normal un-protected site.

When I try and and display them with a simple:

```
<img src ='PASSWORD PROTECTED DIR/Image.jpg">
```

It is asking me to input the username and password.

However, I only want to input the username and password when I actually navigate to the content inside the password protected directory.

I'm using PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whether you're using PHP is irrelevant. What's the server software? Apache?

Comment: Retagged under the assumption of Apache. Please change if it's a different server software

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache.

You can exclude some files inside the `.htaccess` file that defines the password protection.

Untested, but this should work:

```
<Files "path/to/image.jpg"> 
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

but the much much preferable option is to simply place the image outside the protected directory.

Answer (score 0):

without a lot of tricky code, this is basically unsolvable. The `<img>` command says that your user is going to request that information, which is not very different from requesting it directly.

You could start and check how the request was made, filter, make all the images loaded trough php file, etc, but with basic tools it is just not possible.

Requesting an image directly or trough an `<img>` tag is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's PHP you can do like this in a separate file (imgHandler.php)

```
<?php
// Allowed files
$allowedfiles["image1"] = "./the_dir/Image.jpg";
$allowedfiles["image2"] = "./the_dir/Image2.jpg";

function getImage($path) {

    echo file_get_contents($allowedfiles[$path]);
}
getImage($_REQUEST['img']);
?>
```

And then for the images you want to show, just use:

```
<img src="imgHandler.php?img=image1" />
```

This would not prevent caching, and is much securer than the other solution I presented before.

Comment: This is not a good idea at all. It prevents caching, doesn't work in IE < 8, and even in IE is limited to (IIRC) 32 kilobytes

Comment: Edited my answer to a more preferable solution, checked in IE and it caches correctly

Comment: fair enough, but as it stands, this allows a user to get *any*  resource from the protected directory (or any other file on the server that PHP has read access to), a terrible security hole. It would need e.g. an array of allowed files

Comment: @Pekka: True that, and keeping an array with the allowed files is a much securer solution, I will add that, and edit the current function to check for an entry in an array instead, so the users cannot find other images.

Comment: To solve the security problem something should be given, either by a cookie or a tken in the url, to check that the request comes from a regular application page. So there is no security problem, just some more things to add, and this is a good way to prevent direct access to the files except if the request comes from the application. Anyway, if only the appliction should provide access to the images, the pictures should'nt be stored inside the web directory root nd should only be accessed via this handler. (the perfect solution should maybe check some headers as well for IE problems).